# Comparando datas

Tags: java, data

O meu problema, é que eu não estou sabendo como comparar duas datas. Gostaria de comparar um data que o usuário digita, em relação a data atual.

Se a data digita for menor que a atual, o prazo está vencido.

Se a data digita for igual ou maior, o prazo esta para vencer.

Como eu poderia fazer isso ?

o que eu tentei foi:

```
 package calendar;

import com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ValidaData extends JFrame {

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    //JFormattedTextField ft = new JFormattedTextField();
    private final JDateChooser data = new JDateChooser();
    JButton jbCalc = new JButton("Validar");
    JLabel label = new JLabel();

    public ValidaData() {
        setSize(455, 265);
        montaData();
        acao();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public JComponent montaData() {
        JPanel jpData = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(jpData);
        jpData.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jpData, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        jpData.add(data);
        data.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        getContentPane().add("North", data);
        jpData.add(data);
        jpData.add(label);
        label.setText("");
        jpData.add(jbCalc);

        return jpData;
    }

    public void valida(String dataStr) {

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date dataDigitada = null;
        try {

            dataDigitada = df.parse(dataStr);
            Date hoje = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

            if (dataDigitada.compareTo(hoje) > 0) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Vencido!");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "esta para vencer o prazo!");
            }

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // Data digitada está no formato invalido
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void acao() {
        jbCalc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

                valida(data.getDateFormatString());
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ValidaData data = new ValidaData();
        data.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void valida(String dataStr) {

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date dataDigitada = null;
    try {
        // converte a data no formato texto para o formato data
        dataDigitada = df.parse(dataStr);


        Date hoje = Calendar.getInstance().getTime(); // Obtem a data de hoje

        // Definição do metodo compareTo
        // the value 0 if the argument Date is equal to this Date; 
        // a value less than 0 if this Date is before the Date argument; 
        // and a value greater than 0 if this Date is after the Date argument.
        if (dataDigitada.compareTo(hoje) > 0) {
            // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Vencido!");
        } else {
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "esta para vencer o prazo!");
        }

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // Data digitada está no formato invalido
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Basta chamar o metodo valida com a data digitada pelo usuário.

```
valida(ft.getText());
```